# HTML tag class attribute filling is very slow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, coderush

The IntelliSense for the class attribute of html tags freezes VS for 5 seconds on every autocompletion and it really slows me down. I tried to disable the whole feature via : Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Advanced, and Insert attribute value quotes set to false.

But even though I no longer have this IntelliSense, VS keeps freezing for 5 seconds, as if it was still parsing stuff in the background.

What can I do to either solve the main issue or get the feature disabled ?

Thank you

Update : Actually the IntelliSense of HTML attributes is still showing up ! Is there a settings cache I need to clean ?

Comment: Deleting the .suo file worked for me, but lost intelisense for the html